# How many x commands can I use in single SAS program?

Tags: sas

Scenario: I have 100 programs, but all of the programs are not running immediately.

I have used the option `noxwait` and `noxsync`.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I would imagine that would depend on the OS.

Comment: ulimit and /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max will limit the number of processes in linux

Comment: Why would you want to run 100 programs simultaneously?  Sounds like you may want to rethink your approach because if those programs are doing anything non trivial then the machine is likely to grind to a halt.  On the other hand, if what they are doing is trivial, then throw them all into a single program.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe all the 100 x statements execution should go off at the same time. Any external program getting triggered should take time to launch and X statement uses command-prompt window to execute OS specific command. You are already using NOXWAIT and NOXSYNC to make SAS not wait for command to complete and submissions to be asynchronous. The delay should be related to external application start up time.

Also, I do not think there is any limitation on the number of x statement we can use in a single sas program.

Comment: Ok.. I got what type of External Application Start up time..  Any possibilities to over come it.. Thanks in advance.